# Field with ajax select contain data about products reading from the search field

Tags: javascript, ajax, search, shopware

I want to try to create a custom search field by-products.

I just can't figure out how to implement something like this:

> There is a field on the page (any page, it doesn't matter). I enter
> data to search for a product as (on the screenshot 'data 1'). After that, ajax
> loads the data on the found products at the bottom of the field, after
> selecting the product, the product ID must be written in this field in
> order to send this value through the form in the future.

[data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA2l5.png)

It is difficult for me to understand how to implement this since the shopware system is new for me, does anyone have an example of such functionality, or can someone suggest a direction for solving the issue?

This must work like

```
<component name="sw-entity-multi-id-select">
    <name>exampleMultiProductIds</name>
    <entity>product</entity>
    <label>Choose multiple products IDs for the plugin configuration</label>
</component>
```

Or

```
<component name="sw-entity-single-select">
    <name>exampleProduct</name>
    <entity>product</entity>
    <label>Choose a product for the plugin configuration</label>
</component>
```

But for storefront

Comment: There isn't anything like that for the storefront.
You probably need to create your own javascript component and you can use the suggestion endpoint for searching products (just like the default search bar).
Maybe you're lucky and you can find a component that fits your needs and can be configured in such a way that it can work with the suggestion endpoint.